# Error while printing a string in a reverse order using stack

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, compiler-errors

Hello friends this is my first post, I may have done something wrong while posting, sorry for that.

I am trying to print the String in a reverse order using stack. The point where I am trying to get the top value into the character array I am getting error at that part, please help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct StackNode
{
char data;
struct StackNode* next;
};

struct StackNode* createNode(char data){
struct StackNode* stack=(struct StackNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct StackNode));
stack->data=data;
stack->next=NULL;
return stack;
}

void push(struct StackNode** root,char data)
{
struct StackNode* stack=createNode(data);
stack->next=*root;
*root=stack;
}


char top(struct StackNode** root)
{
return (*root)->data;
}
void pop(struct StackNode** root, char c[],int k)
{
int i;
for(i=0;i<=k;i++)
{
c[i]=top(&root);
*root=(*root)->next;
}
}

    void print(struct StackNode* root)
    {
    while(root!=NULL)
    {
    printf("%c",root->data);
    root=root->next;
    printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
    }

int main()
{
struct StackNode* root=NULL;
char c[]="Sherry";
int k=strlen(c);
int i;
for(i=0;i<=k;i++)
{
push(&root,c[i]);
}

pop(&root,c,k);
for(i=0;i<=k;i++)
{
printf("%c",c[i]);
printf(" ");
}




return 0;
}

stackreviseLinkedList.c: In function ‘pop’:
stackreviseLinkedList.c:36:1: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘top’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
 c[i]=top(&root);
 ^
stackreviseLinkedList.c:26:6: note: expected ‘struct StackNode **’ but argument is of type ‘struct StackNode ***’
 char top(struct StackNode** root)
```

Comment: May be `c[i]=top(&root);` causing the error? you might need to remove & operator. As in `c[i]=top(root);` ?

Comment: please correct the indentation and state where the lines with the errors are

Comment: @Giorgi He should also be iterating _only_ until he hits the bottom of the stack.

Comment: The segmentation fault occurs in your last `printf`: you try to print `top(&root)` when `root` is `NULL`. You should implement some means to detect stack underflow.

Comment: Format your code please.

Comment: Debug your code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is clearly pointing out the error here (Disclaimer: Apart from compiler error there could be other issues, I didn't try running the program!)

```
c[i]=top(&root); is the culprit
```

should be

```
c[i]=top(root); // no & required
```

Look at line# 36

```
stackreviseLinkedList.c: In function ‘pop’:
stackreviseLinkedList.c:36:1: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘top’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
 c[i]=top(&root);
 ^
stackreviseLinkedList.c:26:6: note: expected ‘struct StackNode **’ but argument is of type ‘struct StackNode ***’
 char top(struct StackNode** root)
```

Comment: please consider @M Oehm's comment above, more pointers more problem :))

Comment: @Singh: in `main`,  `root` is a `struct StackNode*`, so you need to take its address to get a `struct StackNode**`. In `pop`, `root` is already a `struct StackNode**`, so you can pass it to `top` as is - it is a pointer to the local variable in `main` in both `top` and `pop`.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue that fails you is:

the line:

```
c[i]=top(&root);
```

should be:

```
c[i]=top(root);
```

Other issues that don't hurt you right now but are just bad programming:

- pop() should handle only one character, should be symmetric to push
- you have a memory leak. You should put the StackNode in a temporary pointer, change the root pointer, then release the StackNode
- as I commented, indentation. It help to spot coding issues.